# Why I can't append str into list with loop?

Tags: python

This is about check exam test but I can't add the choice into list like ["B","C","A"] that I want to append or extend it.

```py
ans = list("BCDCADBCCACBADBDBCAB")
a = []
print(ans)

for a in range(1,21):
  b = input("Enter choice : ")
  a.append(b)

if a in ans >= 15:
  print("Pass")
else:
  print("Not pass")
```

Comment: `if a in ans >= 15:` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: In any case, you've trampled over your own definition of `a` by doing `for a in range(1,21):`. Why is everything called `a` and `b`?

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly doest `a` mean, a list ? a number ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using variable name 'a' as list and then to control loop same name variable 'a' so compiler is confused.

```
a = []
for a in range(1,21):
```

change variable to control loop:

```
ans = list("BCDCADBCCACBADBDBCAB")
a = []
print(ans)
for i in range(1,21):
  b = input("Enter choice : ")
  a.append(b)
if a in ans >= 15:
  print("Pass")
else:
  print("Not pass")
```

Comment: Note that `if a in ans >= 15` is interpreted as `if (a in ans) >=15`, and thus it always evaluates to `False`.